# how can i make trisquel look like gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, trisquel

I need to change the trisquel 7.0 look to become like that 
[image]

i knew that trisquel  uses GNOME 3.4.2 but it looks strange, so is there  a way that can i follow to replace the trisquel look with the one in the picture ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - install **gnome-shell** from synaptic package manager

2- restart pc

3 - select **gnome3** from the gdm login screen